# Interval terminology vis-a-vis 'exotic' chords

Tags: discussion

Your quality standards are incomprehensible to me.

What's wrong with asking a question about interval descriptions and including examples of what I believe to be the answer?

Comment: This should be on Meta, and you should describe the specific question your question refers to.

Comment: Hi Dick, this will likely get moved to Meta, since that will be a better spot for this question. When it does so, could you clarify what question you're referring to? A few mentioned that they didn't understand [your other question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/78199/building-a-dominant-triad-in-a-minor-key), but you still got three good answers, an upvote, and it wasn't closed, so it was apparently good enough for our quality standards!

Comment: Nothing. But some - like me - thought the note "spellings" in your other question were hard to read. This issue is about key signatures and enharmonic spellings. If you really do want to know what those comments on the other question were about, try re-phrasing the questions here. I sure several people will offer up answers.

Answer (score 2):

I have just gone in and edited your post, because the main problem with it is that it was not a question.

Even with Richard's edit, we kind of had to guess at what you were asking.

So to answer your specific question here - there is nothing wrong with asking a question about interval descriptions, but you really do need to formulate it as a question :-)

Comment: OK, I'll try again. In the key of C, is (root,M3,P5,m7,M9,m11,m13) the correct interval description for the C13 chord?

Comment: Hi Dick, please see the edits we made to your post. Don't ask in comments. The SE guidelines allow us to grow a collection of good questions and good answers. If you read our [about] and [ask] pages it should make sense.

Comment: @DickRitchie You might also be interested in https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/16828/notation-and-construction-of-13th-chords/